# How to send selected information from Android phone to Hotel Management Software

Tags: java, android

I am developing my first android application for restaurant in which i want to the customer to select the recipes from menu. Now as per my need i have to send the order from particular customer to the Hotel Management Software running on the Reception. I am stuck with the following concerns:

1. How to differentiate identity of order from individual customer ?
2. How to send Acknowledge to the Hotel Management Software and Send response to the customer that order has been placed ?

Comment: Please tell us what have u tried / done?

Comment: @Anukool Thanx Sir for ur response..Sir i have added categories in recipes like Breakfast ,lunch etc ..

Comment: @Anukool ask what you done in android for Android phone to Hotel Management Software.DO u take data from Hotel Management Software to Android phone? Do u added categories to s/w from android phone?

Comment: I wanted to ask about the design part. What have u designed? Whats there in the database? Have you written any code?

Comment: @Anukool Sir i wanted to send the selected information from android to the database running on pc for HMS ...Simply i want to know How can i send info. for particular user from android phone to database running on pc .Thats it

Comment: Webservices is the answer....

Comment: @Anukool Thanx Anukool For ur kind suggestion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Requirement** you have serverside
You have to make one Database at server side, so by using clientid you can distinguish the client. for sending data at Hotel Management Software. you required server-side so you can send request. 
by using 1) XML parsing http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html 

better to use JSON OBJECT its light wight, to read JSON OBJECT its required to parse it. 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

on the basis on you request server will give you response in a form of JSON OBJECT.

Comment: Go with JSON instead of XML.